# Can't send API requests on production heroku app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, axios, nestjs

I deployed an app in Heroku which has an API written in Nest.js, Vue.js UI and PostgreSQL database.

These are the steps I took to build and deploy everything.

1. In my vue directory I ran `vue-cli-service build`
2. in `vue.config.js` I specified my `proxy` and `outputDir` as follows:

```
outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, "../ea-blog-api/public"),
  devServer: {
    proxy: "https://game-bible.herokuapp.com"
  },
```

3. navigating to `ea-blog-api` my file structure looks like so

[image: api file tree]

4. `public` folder contains the compiled output of the vue files..so far so good
5. next I commit and run `git push master heroku`
6. my package.json scripts look like so

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.10.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/main.js",
    "prestart:prod": "yarn tsc",
    "build": "rimraf dist && npm run rebuild && tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "rebuild": "nest build",
    "postinstall": "tsc",
```

7. my Procfile looks like

```
web: npm run start
```

At this point heroku deploys the app and I can access via the browser. When I go to register or login the page renders but when I enter the details into the input fields and click submit I always get

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

This is coming form the Axios interceptor - here is the code

**Login.ts**

```
 async onClickLogin() {
    const userToLogin = {
      username: this.loginForm.username,
      password: this.loginForm.password
    };

    try {
      await UsersModule.LOGIN_USER(userToLogin);
      this.onClickLoginSuccess();
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
```

**UsersLoginModule**

```
@Action({ rawError: true })
  async [LOGIN_USER](params: UserSubmitLogin) {
    const response: any = await login(params);
    if (typeof response !== "undefined") {
      const { accessToken, username, name, uid } = response;

      setToken(accessToken);
      this.SET_UID(uid);
      this.SET_TOKEN(accessToken);
      this.SET_USERNAME(username);
      this.SET_NAME(name);
    }
  }
```

**login function**

```
export const login = (data: UserSubmitLogin) => {
  console.log('users.api - login - data', data) // this logs what I type into the form
  return request({
    url: "/auth/login",
    method: "post",
    data
  });
};
```

**axios request interceptor**
I think the problem is here but I am not sure how I can debug it

```
const service = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 5000
});

// Request interceptors
service.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {

    // Add X-Access-Token header to every request, you can add other custom headers here
    if (UsersModule.token) {
      config.headers["X-Access-Token"] = UsersModule.token;
    }

    logger.request({
      method: config.method,
      url: config.url
    });


    return config;
  },
  error => {
    Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Response interceptors
service.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return response.data;
  },
  error => {
    const { response } = error;
    logger.error(response.data.message, response);
    Message({
      message: `Error: ${response.data.message}`,
      type: "error",
      duration: 5 * 1000
    });
    return Promise.reject({ ...error });
  }
);

export default service;
```

If I test my API against Postman with the heroku url, it returns the correct result from the database and I can verify this by watching `heroku logs --tail`

However, doing the same thing through the UI, there is absolutely no logs coming from the `heroku logs`

I have also verified that my compiled Vue code contains the correct Heroku host url.

Not sure what to do at this point.. any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you get the same error message in dev server (localhost) ?

Comment: @PakpoomTiwakornkit everything works fine on localhost

Comment: Are there any other error messages thrown when you submit the form?

Comment: If I submit the form on heroku app I get this error `Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` - when I look through the Heroku logs I don't see any API calls made so I am guessing there is a problem at the Axios interceptor?

Comment: Could you show the code of `request` function used in `login` function?

Comment: I did, it's part of `service.interceptors.request.use`

Comment: could you add `transformRequest` in `service.interceptors.request.use` and log the value of `data` ?

Comment: I suspect that the error message you're seeing is caused by this line: `logger.error(response.data.message, response);`. It is possible that `response` is `undefined`, so trying to access `data` will give the error message you've reported. Of course there must be some underlying error to get to that line in the first place but you won't be able to see what that is until you fix the error handler.

Comment: @PakpoomTiwakornkit I added `transformRequest` as part of `axios.create` and put a console.log in there but nothing got printed.

Comment: @skirtle `response` is `undefined` but shouldn't there at least be some kind of api hit first?

Comment: @asus That would depend on why it failed. If `response` is `undefined` then that suggests it didn't even get as far as attempting the request. If you fix the problems with the error handler then you should be able to see the real error message, which will hopefully shed some light on what's really going on. In the short term you might want to try just using `console.log(error)`.

Comment: @asus if `transformRequest` print nothing then the error might occur before the request is sent to the server. Could you change the code in `login` function to `request.post("/auth/login", data)` ?

Comment: @skirtle you were right, removing the `logger` and using `console.error` did the trick. I can now see the status code returned from API and in heroku bash I can see what controller methods are hit and can log data there..right now its bunch of 400 or 401s..

Comment: @PakpoomTiwakornkit after removing `logger` as described above, I can see the data being passed in the `transformRequest`

Comment: @asus So your code works now?

Comment: @PakpoomTiwakornkit no still broken. I get 401 when I try to login with the credentials I created via Postman

Comment: @asus Oh okay, that's good news that Vue.js app can send requests to the server. Now the problems are on the server. You might need to post another question specifically for the bugs in the server code.

Comment: @PakpoomTiwakornkit I have added part 2 of the problem. If you have a chance to take a look at it that would be awesome thanks!   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859072/cant-send-api-requests-on-production-heroku-app

Comment: @asus Well, looks like you gave me the wrong link?